# Why IE10 loads older IE version stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I have the following javascript:

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        var isMobile = {
            Android: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
            },
            BlackBerry: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
            },
            iOS: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
            },
            Opera: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
            },
            Windows: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
            },
            any: function () {
                return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
            }
        };

        navigator.sayswho = (function () {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem,
            M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
            if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
                tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
                return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
            }
            M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
            if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i)) != null) M[2] = tem[1];
            return M.join(' ');
        })();
        var browserversion1 = navigator.sayswho.split(" ");
        var browserversion2 = browserversion1[1].split(".")[0].split(",");
        var isIeLessThan10 = (browserversion1[0] == "IE" || browserversion1[0] == "MSIE") && browserversion2[0] < 10
        //alert(isIeLessThan10);

        if (!isMobile.any()) {
            if (isIeLessThan10) {
                alert("IE<10");
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle_ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
            }
            else {
                alert("IE>=10 || !IE");
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("mobile");
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_mobile.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/captionStyle_mobile.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />');
        }
</script>
```

The above script checks to see if the browser is a mobile browser or full feature browser. If it's a full feature browser then check to see if IE version is less than 10 and if it is then load a `defaultStyle_ie.css` stylesheet otherwise if it's IE10 or higher or any other browser load `defaultStyle.css` stylesheet. Everything works as it should in FireFox, Chrome and IE8. When I load the page in IE10, the IE8 version stylesheet is loading. How do I fix that?

Comment: how about conditional comments and not js?

Comment: Would I be able to also use it to validate mobile browser? I am looking to load three different type of stylesheet, `1. for less than IE8` `2. IE10 and higher OR any other browser (FF, Chrome, etc.)` `3. Mobile`

Comment: @skip405 As far as I know conditional comments aren't supported in the newer versions of IE (I think support was removed in IE10, actually).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, that's exactly the point. `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` will load the styles for IE9 and below, while IE10 will simply ignore it

Comment: `<!--[if lte IE 9]>` ie 9 and below stylesheet here `<![endif]-->` and use a media query for mobile.. `<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'..`

Comment: This is why they should start making user agent strings actually useful again; in my IE11, it doesn't even say MSIE anymore `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko`

Comment: @user3326071, if you chose to use conditional comments - you'll need to remove the IE checks completely. Although I would recommend to feature-detect instead.

Comment: @DannyHearnah So how would the end code look like? If you don't mind showing me... thanks

Comment: @skip405 Can you please show me?

Comment: @PaulS. sniffing user agent strings has always been a bad practice, that's why the browser-makers do that. Feature-detect instead

Comment: @user3326071 see my answer for an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, load the normal stylsheets.

Then add a media condition in for mobile.

And then load IE9 or less stylesheet

```
<!-- default stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle.css">

<!-- mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_mobile.css" media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle_mobile.css" media='screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'>

<!-- if ie version 9 or less -->

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/defaultStyle_ie.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theStyles/captionStyle_ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks... When I load it in FIREFOX and CHROME, the mobile stylesheets are also being used. How do I not do that?

Comment: it loads the other stylesheets based on screen width, so are you making your firefox and chrome windows super small? that's probably why that is happening (480px or lower)

Comment: You can change it to suit your needs, i.e you may not want the stylesheet for mobile to be on unless the screen width is less.. 320px? if so, change it on that `media=` line

Comment: The FF browser is maximized :/

Comment: Sorry @user3326071 I didnt add the stylesheet correctly, check now!

Comment: I figured and I modified accordingly but that's how I knew it was loading the mobile stylesheet along with the non mobile :/

Comment: It will load the stylesheet, but should not "action it" until the screen width is met

Comment: Ahhhhhh... I see now. The normal stylesheet will overrule it. Btw what should be the default screen width for a mobile browser?

Comment: yeh that's right - hmm, im not 100% sure and i hope someone corrects me if im wrong but I think 480px covers all of them

Comment: I will search around and see what I find and if it's something different I will post it here. Thanks for the help

Comment: Here is what I found. You want to keep a `min-width` and `max-width`. `<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px)" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> `. Sometime only the `max-width` is sufficient as well.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are in compatible mode in IE, it then sends older version. You can check the mode in development console by hitting F12

Comment: I just checked it says `Browser Mode: IE10 Document Mode: IE9 standards`

Comment: There is something like IE10 (Compatibility mode) or check if the second column is Standard mode

Comment: Yes, it's standard mode

Comment: Is there a meta tag like this present in the `<head>`? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />` If so, take it out. Also, try opening the console and adding a breakpoint in for your browser checks - you'll see exactly what the version is coming back as then.

Comment: I have this line: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /><!-- removes outline for IE9 only-->` which I am using for removing outline around links. Is that conflicting?

Comment: Yes, that causes compatibility issue